# jQuery asynchronous load new element, on a loaded page

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, html-table, row

On my `default.php` I have a jQuery-event that will load an external page in a `<div>` like this:

```
$(".edit").click (function(){
var row_id = $(this).attr('id');
$("#studentCourseElementPlanselected").show().html("<div id='wait'></div>");
$.ajax({
    url: "/pages/loadCoursePlan.php",
    data: { 'cpl_id':row_id },
    success: function(data){
        $("#studentCourseElementPlanselected").html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

On the `/pages/loadCoursePlan.php` (that is loaded) I have another jQuery script that will add a cloned `<select>`-element

```
$('#add_more').on('click', function() {
  var selectClone = $('select:last').clone(true);  // make a copy of select
  $('#courseElements').append(selectClone);    // append to clone select
});
```

And when I click update, another jQuery script is called who does something like this:

```
$('#course_update').click(function() {

var course_id = $('#course_id').val();
var plan_id = $('#plan_id').val();
var price_id = $('#price_id').val();
var course_name = $('#course_name').val();
var course_isActive = $('#course_isActive').val();


$('#update_status').html('<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
$.post('../update.php', {

    course_id: course_id, 
    plan_id: plan_id,
    price_id: price_id,
    course_name: course_name,
    course_isActive: course_isActive

    }, function(data) {
    $('#update_status').html(data);
    return false;
});
});
```

I want the `/pages/loadCoursePlan.php` to be reloaded with the newly object (`plan_id`)

The HTML of the `pages/loadCoursePlan.php` is something like this:

```
<table id='myTable'>

<tr id='7'><td>Some info here</td><td>6 dagar</td> <td><a href='#' class='delete'><div id='remove_row'></div></a></td></tr>
<tr id='15'><td>Some other info here</td><td>10 dagar</td> <td><a href='#' class='delete'><div id='remove_row'></div></a></td></tr>
<tr id='16'><td>More info</td><td>10 dagar</td> <td><a href='#' class='delete'><div id='remove_row'></div></a></td></tr>

</table>
```

I guess I want a new row to be added fair and simple...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by adding a replica of the code i wanted inside the

```
}, function(data) {
$('#update_status').html(data);
return false;
```